# Semi-infinite forms?

Tags: algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, string-theory

I am reading Vafa's paper 'Topological Mirros and Quantum Strings'(arXiv:hep-th/9111017). In this paper, the author says the Hilbert Space of a fermionic string theory corresponds to the space of semi-infinite forms on the loop space.

I only know differential forms (of non-negative degrees) before so I would like to know is there some nice introduction material to this kind of 'semi-infinite form', which can also have negative degrees?

Comment: [This answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/76144/40804) seems relevant.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232014/2451